# Qt GUI - Want to read from .txt file only when the value is changed

Tags: c++, qt, user-interface, dynamic, qtimer

I have implemented a QTimer object to signal a function to read from a .txt file every second and make a new object of another class.
My problem is that I want to limit my function to only create 1 object and keep checking the .txt file for any changes.
How can this be done?

Below is the code that is executed every second

```
void PutMeDown::signalReceived()
{

    char buffer;
    char currentState;
    char prevState = '0';

    int fd = open("/home/stud/test", O_RDWR, 0666);

    if(fd < 0)
        cout << "can't open file" << endl;
    else
        read(fd, &buffer, 1);//read from file

    currentState = buffer;

    if(currentState == prevState)
    {

        drive = new Drive(this);
        drive->setWindowFlags(Qt::Window | Qt::FramelessWindowHint);
        drive->show();
        this->hide();

    }

    close(fd);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

There is special class in `Qt` - `QFileSystemWatcher`. This class can tell you that file was changed (`fileChanged` signal).

```
QFileSystemWatcher * watcher = new QFileSystemWatcher(this);
watcher->addPath(mFileName);
connect(watcher,SIGNAL(fileChanged(QString)),SLOT(slot(QString)));
```

In slot you can read file or do something else. With this class you don't need to use `QTimer`, it can be better than checking file every second.

Back to your question about 1 object. The simplest solution is to provide additional `bool` variable, check this variable in slot and create new object or not. You can also provide some way to change this variable "outside", so your object will be created when you need this.

Also I see that you use `non-Qt` approach for reading file. There is special class in `Qt` too: [QFile](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qfile.html). Check it, maybe your task allows you to use `QFile`.

Comment: @MichaelTJ Thank you for your comment, I was little confused because someone downvote my answer and cancel downvoting immediately, that's why I thought that my answer is not suitable(misunderstood something) but now I see that all is fine.

Comment: @MichaelTJ If the answer was helpful to you and solved your problem, please mark it as accepted. Otherwise chances are next time nobody will be so generous in helping you...